# I have a DataFrame of 4 mln rows and try to convert one column values from string to JSON and got memory problem. How can I improve my code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

df (about 4mln rows):

```
| ID       | Date      | Metric  | json_value                             
| -------- | --------- | ------- |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 2020-01-01|    1    |'{"Id":1, "experiment":[{"Name":"a1", "value1":1}, {},...{"Name":"a200", "value200":200}]}'  |
```

I do:

```
df['json_value'] = [json.loads(x) for x in df['json_value']]
```

And get mistake "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."
Can I make it differently or the problem in the size of df?

(If it helps, I want to make group by pair: Date and each value from experiment consistently and count average metric for each group by)

Comment: You need to load the data in chunk and apply operation and save for that chunk. You can't apply a loop to the whole data as you are loading the whole data into memory. I guess it's time for you to move to some big data technologies like pyspark.

Comment: Use pickle for storing the dataframe(modified), apply multiprocessing : https://www.quora.com/Can-Python-Pandas-handle-10-million-rows-What-are-some-useful-techniques-to-work-with-the-large-data-frames

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could declare a function

```
def load_json(x):
 return json.loads()
```

and then do

```
df['json_value'] = df['json_value'].apply(load_json)
```

Still, everything depends on the size of the jsons you're loading.